# The NumberFormatter function I made for JFormattedTextField, doesn't allow typing decimal numbers

Tags: java, decimalformat, jformattedtextfield, numberformatter

In order to limit user's input to a specific numeric range I created this function:

```
public static final Locale GR=new Locale("el", "GR");

public static NumberFormatter getMyNumberFormatter(){
    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getInstance(GR));
    formatter.setValueClass(Double.class);
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
    formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
    formatter.setMaximum(10000000.0);
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(GR);
    df.setGroupingUsed(true);
    formatter.setFormat(df);
    return formatter;
}
```

I applied this formatter to a **JFormatedTextfield** but it worked **only** on integer values. I want user to be able to type float numeric values from 0.0 to 10000000.0 but the current formatter allows only integers. Automatic grouping works perfect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can it be you need to type a **comma** as [decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) - Greek?

Comment: Have you tried BigDecimal instead of Double as value class?

Comment: @JoopEggen The locale is set to Greek (new Locale("el", "GR")) so comma as decimal mark shouldn't be a problem. Just in case, I tested it with the US locale ('.' for decimal mark) and had the same problem.

Comment: @dpr When I change setValueClass(Double.class) to setValueClass(BigDecimal.class) the formatter doesn't allow any character for input (for some strange reason). The same thing happens if I use Float.class.

Comment: Sorry, then it is something like `new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat("0.0###"))` as in the answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen Exactly. The pattern addition solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I remember `JFormattedTextField` is a pain to use.

I assume that the DecimalFormat is not allowing numbers with just a decimal point, based on the following section of the javadoc:

> If you are going to allow the user to enter decimal values, you should either force the DecimalFormat to contain at least one decimal (#.0###), or allow the value to be invalid `setAllowsInvalid(true)`. Otherwise users may not be able to input decimal values.

You can also try to add

```
df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
```

One note: it is a bit confusing that the JFTF is created using one NumberFormat and later a new one is set. More straightforward (not tested):

```
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(GR);
df.setGroupingUsed(true);
df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(df);
...
```

or just

```
NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter();
...
formatter.setFormat(df);
```

**Suggestion** (better IMO than using a JFTF):

Extend a `DocumentFilter` and set it as filter of a new PlainDocument. Use a JTextField that uses that document.

Comment: Problem solved when I added `df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true)` and `df.applyPattern("###,##0.00")`. When I added the first, the formatter was allowing all numbers except 0 (zero) but when I applied a pattern that solved too. Thank you very much and yes JFormatedTextField is a pain indeed.